# How to create OpenSolaris self bunle volume on EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, opensolaris

I'm using OpenSolaris 2008.11 on EC2.
I want to create self bundle .
in ubuntu

```
sudo ec2-bundle-vol -d /mnt -k $EC2_PRIVATE_KEY  -c $EC2_CERT  --fstab /etc/fstab --user $AWS_ACCUNT_ID  -r i386
```

but OpenSolaris does not have /etc/fstab

Do you know?

Answer (score 2):

Solaris uses /etc/vfstab not /etc/fstab

Here are some links talking about how to use e2c on solaris:

http://www.sun.com/third-party/global/amazon/start/index.jsp
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=93069